# Create a div for every line in the excel sheet

Tags: html, excel

I use this here to read my xlsx files: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HUYwnlGF5DQ
But how can I use the information, and add for every new line a new div with the information in the excel sheet?

My code:

```
<script src="unpkg.com/read-excel-file@4.x/bundle/…> 
<input type="file" id="input">
let input = document.getElementById('input')
input.addEventListener('change', function(){
readXlsxFile(input.files[0]).then(function(data){ console.log(data) })
}) </script
```

Comment: Please include [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Your question is also not very specific, Can you elaborate on what the question is? this might also be useful [How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: This here is my code:
``
<script src="https://unpkg.com/read-excel-file@4.x/bundle/read-excel-file.min.js"></script>
            
            <input type="file" id="input">
            <table id="tbl-data"></table>

            <script>
              let input = document.getElementById('input')
              input.addEventListener('change', function(){
                readXlsxFile(input.files[0]).then(function(data){
                  console.log(data)
                })
              })
            </script
``

Comment: Don't post code in a comment, edit the original question and add it there.

Comment: I do it in the original question